# Replace colors in SVG file with Regex and PHP

Tags: php, regex

I need to replace certain colors inside an SVG file

Below is what I have so far but it does not replace anything and give nor errors.

Can someone help with the regex part please?

```
// Define Default Color Name and Hexcode values
$colorsArray = array(
    'red' => 'FF0000',
    'orange' => 'FF5000',
    'yellow' => 'FFF200',
    // ...
);

$svgImageName = 'my-svg-file.svg';

$svgRawString = file_get_contents($svgImageName);

foreach ($colorsArray as $colorName => $colorCode) {

    $svgOutput = preg_replace(
         '/#([0-9a-f]{6})/',
        '#'.$colorsArray[$newColorName],
        $svgRawString
    );

}


echo '<textarea rows="20" cols="100">' .$svgOutput. '</textarea><hr>';
```

Here is example output from my SVG File...

```
<path fill="#FFFFFF" d="M2129.319,78.436c-8.375,0-15.165,6.79-15.165,15.165v748.803c0,8.375,6.79,15.165,15.165,15.165
                s15.165-6.79,15.165-15.165V93.601C2144.484,85.225,2137.694,78.436,2129.319,78.436z"/>
            <path fill="#FF0000" d="M183.587,78.436c-8.375,0-15.165,6.79-15.165,15.165v748.803c0,8.375,6.79,15.165,15.165,15.165
                s15.165-6.79,15.165-15.165V93.601C198.752,85.225,191.963,78.436,183.587,78.436z"/>
```

Comment: Your problem is also the variable logic. You're reusing the unaltered input variable, and the loop thus only replaces the last colorcode. (Apart from the iteration over color names and not previous RGB strings; at what your last question hints.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex matches only lowercase characters, add the `i` modifier to match case insensitive:

`/#([0-9a-f]{6})/i`

Comment: Your answer is right for my question but my logic is wrong.  What this does is replace all colors with the last color in my array as it loops since it just re-sets ALL the colors on each loop.  So what I really need to do is something like this `'/#($colorCode)/i'` or `'/#$colorCode/i'` yet it does not seem to work.  Any suggestions?

Comment: @jasondavis It does not work because you're using single quotes, use double instead. Although you may also look into `preg_quote` later on.

Comment: @jasondavis Just tell me what you want to do ? Replace `#FF0000` by `red` ? Also what's the PHP version you're using ?

Comment: Thanks I got it fixed now.  I added `$svgRawString = $svgOutput;` at the bottom inside my foreach loop so that it does not reset the variable on each iteration like it was before

Comment: @jasondavis ok, otherwise ping me at [regex](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25767/regex)